# Converting text to html table using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am converting my space separated text using into a html table.
This is the code that I am using, but the output does not contain '|' which I can trying to use as a tab replacement.

```
function tabs_to_table($input) {

                               define('TAB_REPLACEMENT', "|");
                               define('NEWLINE_REPLACEMENT', "\n");
                               define('ROW_BEGIN', "");
                               define('TABLE_BEGIN', "\n");
                               define('TABLE_END', "\n"); 
                               $input = preg_replace("/\t/", TAB_REPLACEMENT  , $input);
                               $rows = preg_split("/\r\n/", $input);     
                               $output = "";
                               foreach ($rows as $index => $row) {
                                   if (strlen($row) > 0) {
                                       $output .= ROW_BEGIN . $row . NEWLINE_REPLACEMENT;
                                   }
                                }

                               //build table
                               $input = TABLE_BEGIN . $output . TABLE_END;

                               return $input;
                            }
```

The output is

```
aggr0 367GB 350GB 17GB 95%
aggr0/.snapshot 0TB 0TB 0TB 0%
aggr1 1102GB 554GB 547GB 50%
aggr1/.snapshot 0TB 0TB 0TB 0%
```

but I want

```
aggr0          |367GB |350GB|17GB |95%
aggr0/.snapshot|0TB   |0TB  |0TB  |0%
aggr1          |1102GB|554GB|547GB|50%
aggr1/.snapshot|0TB   |0TB  |0TB  |0%
```

Can someone please point-out what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: I think using a html table is better... as your row might have dynamic length

Answer (score 0):

You need str_pad() function for this, look here for more info:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_pad.asp